# How to get images into Heroku PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, blob

I have a PostgreSQL database on Heroku and I would like to store a small amount of images in it. I created a column of the `bytea` data type to hold them.

Is it possible to get the images directly from my computer into the database? If so, how should I do it? I already tried getting it done by using `pg_read_binary_file`, but then I get the error "*permission denied for function pg_read_binary_file*"

In case it is only possible when the images are already on the database server, how do I get them there on Heroku?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: What kind of images? User uploads? Something else? And why are you storing them in the database? This is usually an antipattern.

Comment: They are JPG images. I am the only one uploading them, users cannot. I am storing them in the database since there are only a few and it seemed more convenient to me than referencing them

Comment: "I am the only one uploading them"—does this mean you are able to upload them locally? How are you doing that? What's stopping you from just doing the same thing with the Heroku-hosted database?

Comment: No I meant that users will be unable to get images into the database (because you asked about user uploads). The point is that I don't know how to get images into the database, neither locally nor to Heroku, because I have no experience with this. I hope you can help :)

Comment: My advice is _not_ to do this. But if you're determined to, how do you get _other_ data into your database? You need a client of some kind. Which one are you using? It can probably put binary data in, too. (And how do you plan to get the data _out_? How will you use it?)

Comment: I am using the Heroku CLI (which uses psql) to get other data into it. I tried `pg_read_binary_file` to get the binary data into the db, but this gave me an error. And I am getting data out using npm pg in Express.

I am not determined to put data directly into the db if there is a better alternative. Can you explain your advice not to do it, even if it concerns only a small amount of data? And how would the alternative work? Store the images on the server and reference them by a string attribute in the db? Thanks again.